# Does Google charge to monitor hacked Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, security

My friend's Gmail account was hacked. After notifying Google and getting the password changed, he was offered a service to monitor his account for a year for $100 or three years for $300. His wife paid for a year's service with her credit card. Now he is concerned that he may have been scammed. Would like to verify that this service is legitimate.

I am the manager of computer support for the hospital where we both work. I'd like to know the answer to this question because I am often consulted for advice as to which mail customer to use and about potential scams.

Comment: He was almost certainly scammed.  I've never heard of Google offering anything remotely like this, nor do I know what on Earth it could actually entail.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I am not familiar with any such paid service by official google.

If you do want to protect your gmail (or any other service ) the following is a good read

http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2011/06/02/how-to-stop-your-gmail-account-being-hacked/

As for using Google as your mail service: it's just as secure as your users will keep it. I run a 80 users company on Google Apps - no issues for the past 6 years.